# API Manager documentation in DCAT

Tags: wso2

I would like to ba able to expose documentation of each API in DCAT format.

Is it possible to do this and any hi8nt on how?

Thanks

Luca

Comment: No currently we dont support this..

Answer (score 0):

API Manager can treat documents as external entities. So you can use whatever format you want, and then reference them form the API manager.

Comment: I preferred an approach where API documentation is generated basing on the information that is already present in WSDL or general registry entries.  Is it possible to implement something that produce an output from data in the registry and some hint on how to approach? - Luca